# MPAndroidChart BarChart hanging onto unused entries - how to remove them?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have an MPAndroidChart being populated dynamically by selecting CheckBoxes in a dialog, and I have three Spinners that I use to filter my data.

Now, here is my problem.  My filters don't seem to be working properly.  I verified the size of my `BarEntry` List after applying the filters and it appears to be correct.  However, if Filter A is selected and the data contains this:
A-A-B-B-A-A

The X axis labels will show for both A and B, with B showing no data.  However, if Filter B is selected, only the labels and data for B will show.

I have the following code to create my chart:

```
mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "Arimo-Regular.ttf");

final XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

xAxis.setTypeface(tf);
xAxis.setTextSize(16f);


IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        int intValue = (int) value;
        if (tests.size() <= 6) {
            return (tests.size() > intValue && intValue >= 0) ? tests.get(intValue) : "";
        } else {
            return (testsSix.size() > intValue && intValue >= 0) ? testsSix.get(intValue) : "";
        }
    }
};

 xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);

 YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
 yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
 yAxis.setLabelCount(10, false);
 yAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
 yAxis.setTypeface(tf);
 yAxis.setTextSize(16f);
 yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

 YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
 rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

 Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
 l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
 l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
 l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
 l.setDrawInside(false);
 l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
 l.setFormSize(9f);
 l.setTextSize(16f);
 l.setXEntrySpace(4f);

 if (mChart.getData() != null &&
      mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {

      set1 = (BarDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
      set1.setValues(barEntries);
      set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
      mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
      mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
      mChart.invalidate();
 } else {
      set1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Tests");
      set1.setDrawIcons(false);
      set1.setColors(0xFFAB3585);
      set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
      ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
      dataSets.clear();
      dataSets.add(set1);

      BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
      data.setValueTextSize(16f);
      data.setValueTypeface(tf);
      data.setValueFormatter(new IValueFormatter() {
          @Override
          public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
              return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f", value);
          }
      });
      data.setBarWidth(0.9f);
      mChart.setData(data);
  }
```

`barEntries` gets repopulated each time I apply a filter with my Spinners.  As I stated, I verified its size and it is correct when I apply the filter, so it appears that my filter is working properly, but the BarChart isn't displaying the filtered data properly.  I think there is something that is causing the BarChart to hang onto entries that contain my B filter, except without displaying their data.

Is there any way around this or is this a bug in MPAndroidChart?

Answer (score 0):

Cut following lines from your code:

```
  mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
  mChart.invalidate();
```

Paste them after:

```
mChart.setData(data);
```

Comment: Let me know for further assistance.